# Unity iOS build containing Admob causes error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob, google-mobile-ads

My project uses Admob to display ads. It works on Android but not on iOS. Build with Xcode is successful. When running the app in Xcode on simulator, I get the following runtime error:

Symbol not found: OBJC_CLASS$_GADInterstitialAd

Used the latest versions of:
external-dependency-manager-1.2.175.unitypackage
GoogleMobileAds-v7.4.0.unitypackage
Unity 2021.3.18f1
Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e)

Contents of Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/1.2.175/AdMob_Dependencies.xml include iOS configuration:

```
  <!-- iOS Cocoapod dependencies can be specified by each iosPod element. -->
  <iosPods>
    <iosPod name="Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK" version="~> 7.4" bitcodeEnabled="true"
            minTargetSdk="14.0" addToAllTargets="false" />
      <!-- Set of source URIs to search for this Cocoapod spec.
           By default Cocoapods will attempt to fetch the pod specs from:
           * $HOME/.cocoapods/repos
           * https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
           -->
      <sources>
        <source>https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs</source>
      </sources>
  </iosPods>
```

I tried all versions of GoogleMobileAds from v7.0 to v7.4 unsuccessfully.

Comment: The simulator requires native libraries compatible with it. I would guess that AdMob does not provide those. We often have to remove or stub plugins for simulator builds for that reason.

Comment: I am using admob with unity and testing on simulator from 2016 - it worked all the time.

Comment: Latest successfully build was in 2021. The issue appeared after upgrading the versions of all products including Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK, required to comply with Families policy restrictions.